# Update/cancel event in Google Email Markup

Tags: gmail, google-schemas, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I can successfully add an event to an HTML confirmation email using the following markup:

```json
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "EventReservation",
"reservationNumber": "9973180",
"reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
"underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
},
"reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Test Event"
},
"startDate": "2018-04-19T11:30:00+03:00",
"endDate": "2018-04-19T12:30:00+03:00",
"location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "347 West 55th St",
        "addressLocality": "New York",
        "addressRegion": "NY",
        "postalCode": "10019",
        "addressCountry": "US"
    }
}
}
```

However, I am unable to:

1. Update the event by sending the same markup with a different `startDate` and a `modifiedTime`
2. Cancel the event by sending the same markup with `reservationStatus` = `http://schema.org/Cancelled` and a `modifiedTime`

Comment: Could you please post your markup for (1) and (2)?

Comment: I have the same problem. But when i test with "Google Apps Script" (https://script.google.com) the event gets deleted. When i use the same code on my server the event gets created but not deleted. (SPF and DKIM are both configured correctly)